# How to handle additional space got appended in svn directories during svn-git migration?

Tags: git, svn, tortoisesvn, git-svn

SVN Url : https://svn.tech.boom/test/my%20repo

if i clone above url it is throwing following error and started scanning the svn repo.

File not found /test/my%20repo path, test/my%20repo

Comment: The URL doesn't work for me. And it's inhumanly hard to help you with this level of detail like you provided. Please see [How to ask a good question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

we should not create svn repo directories with space like (my repo). As a work around i have copied the content to different folder and migrate it to GIT